# Spark Dataset - Average function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Spark with Scala, and trying to find the best way to group `Dataset` by key, and get average + sum together.

For example,

- I have `Dataset[Player]` , and `Player` consists of: playerId , yearSignup, level , points.
- I want to group this dataset by yearSignup , and to calculate for every year: sum of points, and average level.
- So with `groupByKey(p=>p.yearSignup)` , and `reduceGroups(p1,p2)` , I can get the sum of points: `(p1.points ++ p2.points)` with `reduceLeft`.

But how to get the average level? Should I sum it first, and after that group again and divide it?
Or there is another way to do it together.

Comment: you can use the stat functioons.. btw, can you paste sample input

Answer (score 1):

After you `groupby`, you can use `.agg` for both `sum` and `avg`. ([see docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html))

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Player
  .groupBy($"yearSignup")
  .agg(
    avg($"level").as("avg_level")
    sum($"points").as("total_points")
  )
```

Comment: whaps you said dataset- same general concept docstrings are here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)